# How can I remove this 'click' dependency and just get the function to happen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using a set of buttons to replace the `src` of an iframe embed, and I'd like to set the class for the selected button as 'current-vid'. I have been able to call the JavaScript function t replace the `src` successfully:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function go(loc){
        document.getElementById('playthis').src = loc;
    }
</script>
```

by using the following `onclick`:

```
<div id="Vid-Nav-1">
    <button class="btn current-vid" onclick = "go('url#1')">Video #1</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick = "go('url#2')">Video #2</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick = "go('url#3')">Video #3</button>
</div>
```

Problem >> How can get the `onclick` event in the button to ALSO include the following?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('#Vid-Nav-1 button').on('click', function() {
            $(this).addClass('current-vid').siblings().removeClass('current-vid');
        });
    });
</script>
```

It doesn't work in its current form. I'm using Wordpress if that is of relevance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having onclicks, you should just store the `url#1` in an element attribute and grab it later. That way your javascript is all in one place, and not spread throughout your html.

```
<div id="Vid-Nav-1">
   <button class="btn current-vid" loc="url#1">Video #1</button>
   <button class="btn" loc="url#2">Video #2</button>
   <button class="btn" loc="url#3">Video #3</button>
</div>
```

The javascript/jquery could look like this

```
$("#Vid-Nav-1").on("click",".btn", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //Store current element in variable
    var me = $(this);

    //Test if it is already current
    if(!me.hasClass('current-vid')){
        //Get iframe loc/or whatever that is and change src
        //the .attr('loc') pulls the data stored in the corresponding attribute loc=""
        document.getElementById('playthis').src = me.attr('loc');

        //Change button class
        //when use siblings put class or something
        //if you add other stuff later, it could break
        me.addClass('current-vid').siblings('.btn').removeClass('current-vid');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks - this is an elegant solution, but I can't get jQuery code to work in my wordpress site (noob), so I'd like to find a pure JS solution if possible.